# initializing a data structure in C to manage a pool of memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc, calloc

i am writing a simple function for a library, that will take in as a parameter the size of memory to be managed by my other functions.

i have a data structure that holds the information of this large memory pool initialized by the user.

```
typedef struct memBlock{
    struct memBlock* next;
    unsigned int size;  // Size of this block
    unsigned int is_used;  // bool 0 = not used 1 = used
}  memBlock;
```

I also have this function that i am trying to figure out how to initialize this data structure as well as allocate enough space to be managed initially?

```
int initialize_memory(unsigned long size){

    memBlock *ptr; // the beginning of our whole memory to be handled

    ptr = malloc(size); // this is the ptr to the original memory first allocated.
    ptr->next = NULL;
    ptr->size = NULL;
    ptr->is_used = 0;

    has_initialized = 1; // the memory has been initialized
}
```

please help

Comment: Sorry, what's the issue? There's no way for us to know how much memory you will need in your memory pool. Is there? :)

Comment: And the question is...?  ("please help" does not count.)

Comment: Sorry about the vague question here, in my initialize_memory function i have a large pool of memory which will be reserved when this function is called. i am trying to figure out if the initialization calls (ptr->next....) are correct at the beginning? Essentially i also have another function that will act like 'malloc' to reserve a number of bytes but will first check this data structure to see if any memory is available from my pool? my basic question is did i initialize this data structure correctly at the beginning before any memory has been allocated from my ptr?

Comment: @Warz There's no question here. Do you plan to post every line of code you ever write and ask if it's correct? What do **you** think? Do you think it is correct, or isn't, and if not why? You set `ptr->next` to `NULL` ... do you think that's right? If not, why not? It **seems** reasonable. You set `ptr->size` to `NULL` ... do you think that's right? It sure doesn't **seem** right, does it? If you can't answer these questions, then you're not nearly ready to write this program.

Comment: @Jim, first of all i appreciate the response. Secondly the reason i asked this improper question was not to show my level of expertise on memory management. i was a bit confused by my own data structure and was still trying to figure how to managed a set size of memory so i dont loose any information (what has been freed, how much do i have left...) later on. The reference to the line particularly was just to show where i had the most confusion. once again thanks for your post

Comment: @Warz You're asking how to write a memory pool implementation, with a whole lot of sub-questions, of which the one you asked above is just the tip of the iceberg. That's too broad. I suggest that you google around for memory allocators in C and read their descriptions and code ... e.g., the glibc malloc is open source. I believe the original author was Doug Lea; google him, as he has written a number of articles and perhaps even books on how to design a memory allocator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ptr->size = NULL;` to `ptr->size = size;`. You also need to return `ptr`, or store it somewhere. Your function returns `int`, but you don't return anything. `has_initialized` seems unnecessary -- you know you've initialized because your memory pool (the `ptr` value you will return) isn't `NULL`. If you need more help than that, you're going to have to explain more.

Addendum: You need to decide whether memBlock.size is the size of the allocated space or the size of the memory block represented by the memBlock ... if the  latter, then you need to account for the space occupied by the memblock itself by subtracting that off the amount of space you allocated: `ptr->size = size - sizeof(struct memBlock);` You also need a way to address your memory pool ... since that immediately follows the memBlock, its address is `(ptr + 1)` or `&ptr[1]` (if you don't understand that, look up "pointer arithmetic in C").

P.S. You wrote in a comment "Essentially i also have another function that will act like 'malloc' to reserve a number of bytes but will first check this data structure to see if any memory is available from my pool"

Why do you want to do that? malloc already manages memory far better than your function will, considering the skill level and time invested, and there's no point in layering another memory allocator on top of it. Unless this is a school project to write a memory allocator, in which case you should say that up front.

Comment: Once again great explanation, i had the has_initialized line to call the initializing function if someone tried to call the "allocate function" i am currently writing without every allocating some level of memory that will be managed. I am writing this function yes for a course however i did not mean for anyone to give me answers.One more question for you, to address the memory pool i am managing you mentioned (ptr + 1) as the way to look through the initialized memory. how do you check in c if someone tries to allocate space from my memory pool that is larger than what is currently available?

Comment: @Warz Your memory pool is a linked list. After an arbitrary sequence of  allocations and frees, you can end up with several free blocks in that list (google "fragmentation"; also google "coalesce", both in conjunction with malloc or memory allocation). You will need to search the list for a free block large enough to hold the size requested (google "first fit" and "best fit"). If someone tries to allocate more than is available, you will know because that search will fail (this is what happens when malloc returns NULL).

Comment: @Warz "you mentioned (ptr + 1) as the way to look through the initialized memory" No, that's not what I'm saying. You look through the blocks by starting at the list head (the value that should be returned by or stored by `initialize_memory`) and following the `next` links. Given a `struct memBlock* ptr` pointing to some memBlock, you can access `next` and `size` by the field names, but how to access the free memory itself? That can be done with `(void*)&ptr[1]` -- that's a pointer to the first byte just beyond the memBlock header.

Comment: +1 - Additionally, the information in the structure presented can't be taken as accurate since malloc() is free to round the `size_t` argument to the next byte aligned value.

Comment: @Tim Which information isn't accurate? malloc is guaranteed to return at least `size` bytes, which is all that is being depended upon. That it may block off a few extra bytes from _its_ memory pool doesn't seem like an issue, considering that `initialize_memory` will only be called once.

Comment: @jim, sorry to re-open this question but, every time my_alloc is called it needs to create a new node and added to the linked_list correct? how do i initialize my linked list inside of mm_init?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct memBlock {
   unsigned int size;
   unsigned int initialized;
   void* block;
} memBlock;

memBlock* new_memBlock(unsigned int size)
{
    memBlock* memblock;

    memblock = malloc(sizeof(memBlock));

    if (memblock)
    {
        memblock->size = size;
        memblock->block = malloc(size);

        if (memblock->block)
            memblock->initialized = 1;
    }

    return memblock;
}

void free_memBlock(memBlock** memblock)
{
    if (*memblock)
    {
        free(*memblock->block)
        *memblock->block = 0;
    }

    free(*memblock);
    *memblock = 0;
}

void main()
{
    memBlock* memblock = new_memBlock(1024);

    if (memblock && memblock->initialized)
        printf("Initialized\n");
    else
        printf("Not initialized\n");

    free_memBlock(&memblock);
}
```

Comment: This really isn't what the OP wants ... note the `next` field in `struct memBlock`, and the name of the function, `initialize_memory`. The idea is to maintain a pool (or "arena" in malloc terminology) of free memory blocks, and `initialize_memory` initializes the pool. And the double `malloc` isn't necessary ... `struct memBlock` is a header and the free memory can simply follow it at `(ptr + 1)` ... just as most implementations of malloc do it.

Comment: Correction to my comment: Actually its an arena of free and allocated blocks -- note the `is_used` flag. free and allocated blocks sit next to each other in memory, and presumably free blocks are coalesced when freed. At least, that's how malloc works and this seems to just be an implementation of malloc.